# HDD failure and format error, shows 4.1 GB instead of 1.86 TB

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, fdisk, secure-erase, hdparm

I have a Seagate 2.0 TB HDD. I had Ubuntu installed on it and grub on my SSD. I removed the cable when trying to change it. After that when I plugged it in grub showed the black error screen with `grub>`. I had a dual boot on the SSD with Windows and I removed it by fresh-installing Ubuntu.

My HDD showed an error when I opened it in disk management on Windows originally and asked about creating GPT or MBR but both commands failed. Additionally it showed on 3.9 GB as the maximum available/formatable size.

Now I am on Ubuntu. My drive shows up in disk menu as 4.1 GB, not 1.84 TB, as does another of my correctly working 2 TB one, but not in fdisk. I tried secure erase but it gives an error.

[image]

Error when secure erasing:

> Issuing SECURITY_ERASE command, password="pwdsw", user=user SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]: 70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 04 51 40 00 21 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]: 70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 04 51 40 01 21 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Comment: 1) Please see [Hard Drive error: bad/missing sense data](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768373/hard-drive-error-bad-missing-sense-data). 2) Do you need to recover any data from the Seagate 2.0 TB HDD?

Comment: No I do not need to recover any data, secondly I saw the answer but mine was plugged in directly by SATA although a cheaper cabke but that didnt give any major errors in the past. I will try sdparm one though.

Comment: Have you tried using Seagate's SeaTools to check the drive?

Comment: I remember correctly it did show some error but nothing that was helpful.

Comment: You might as well use SeaTools to format (not just erase) the drive and see if it corrects the problem. Does it report the correct drive model?